# visual studio 2012 - publish windows forms app for windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1

I created a very simple windows form app in visual studio 2012 on a Windows 7 machine that has been working on Windows 7 for a few years with no issues.  The user upgraded to Windows 8.1 recently and when I tried to install the app, there is no error message but it doesn't work.  It appears to install and creates the desktop shortcut but the application won't launch. What I can I do to make it work on Windows 8.1? I've tried using the 'run application made for previous versions of windows" but the app doesn't appear on the list and I can't seem to find the location when I try to browse to it.  It seems like it should be a simple fix but I'm very inexperienced and need some help.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: post more details about what the application is doing and which technologies have you used in the application

Comment: Ok, anything specific besides what I've already posted? I developed a windows form app using Visual Studio 2012 on a Windows 7 machine. Now I want to deploy the app to a Windows 8.1 machine.  When I try to install it, it appears to install, the desktop shortcut shows up but the application won't launch. What settings can I change in Visual Studio?  Target cpu? I've tried AnyCPU and x64. Target framework? I've set it to 4.5. I'm looking for any suggestions so I can try get this working.  If you require more info, please tell me what I need to provide.  I'm not an  experienced programmer.

Comment: we NEED much more details. What is your app doing? Which libraries do you use?

Comment: When the app works properly it allows people to enter information through a form that ends up in an Access DB. They can also edit data and export search results to Excel. The libraries referenced in the project are Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (14.0), System, System.Core, System.Data, System.Data.dataSetExtensions, System.Deployment, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms, System.Xml, System.Xml.Linq

Comment: Have you installed Excel on the Windows 8.1?